# What does host's top command show about CPU/Memory utilization by kubenetes pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes

If I issue top command in a node of a kubenetes cluster, would it show CPU and Memory utilization of processes that are running inside docker as part of Kubenetes cluster? If so how would they be named?

Comment: What are you using this data for?  You don't normally directly log into nodes, and tools like the cluster autoscaler can delete them outside your direct control.

Comment: I just wanted to check if cluster is utilizing VM's properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see from [Isolate containers with a user namespace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/)

> Linux namespaces provide isolation for running processes, limiting their access to system resources without the running process being aware of the limitations

Docker uses [Linux namespaces](https://www.linux.com/news/understanding-and-securing-linux-namespaces/) to isolate the processes, it never changes the fact, the processes running in docker is simply ones in host with limitations.

So you can always see the CPU and Memory utilization of all the processes inside or outside Docker.

For how would they be named, they named with the process name run inside docker.

Comment: @PrapEr Thank you. Does this mean I can issue gstack/jstack commands from host to get thread dumps of processes running inside docker?

Comment: @peter yes, I have not tried that, but it would functionally work, although you might get some permission problems.